# Новый хром, blink и префиксы

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, html, css

*Вышел новый хром. С новым движком. Пока старые добрые `-webkit` префиксы фурычат. `-blink` пока хром не распознает вообще* **Вопросы:**

1. Что будет с префиксом `-webkit`. Оставят? Если да, то будут ли добавлять в будущем новые свойства из вебкита?
2. Появится ли `-blink`? Переведут ли все `-webkit` свойства на `-blink` (т.е. `-webkit-user-select` в `-blink-user-select`). Будут ли новые свойства называть `-blink`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Официальную информацию о префиксах в Blink можно найти [по ссылке](http://www.chromium.org/blink) (раздел "Vendor Prefixes"). Но там совсем немного. Ответы:

1. Новые свойства с префиксом -webkit точно добавлять не будут. Насчет существующих не все ясно. Есть интервью с разработчиками, где они [отвечают на этот вопрос](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TlJob8K_OwE#t=29m03s). Говорят, что постараются ничего не сломать. Мне кажется пока можно не беспокоиться, но лучше стараться указывать помимо -webkit свойства еще и версию без префикса.
2. Нет, префикса -blink не будет. Более-менее стандартизованные фичи будут работать без префикса, экспериментальные тоже будут работать без префикса, но только если их активировать в about:config.